# 編集の頻度の指針はありますか？

Tags: 討議

SOは編集を行うことで新着の投稿欄に表示されます。

この機能は悪用すれば、高頻度で編集し続けることで、新着欄を自身のポストで埋めるといったことも可能だと思いますが、この辺りに明確な指針ってあるんでしょうか？

---

ヘルプセンターの「[質問に誰も回答してくれない場合は?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)」には、

> まず、よい質問を投稿したかどうか確認します。よい回答を得るには質問に対してさらに努力する必要がある場合もあります。質問を編集してステータスと進捗の最新情報を提示します。質問に回答するために自分が続けている努力について説明します。これにより、質問がホームページに自然に上昇し、より多くの人が興味を持ってくれます。

「質問に回答するために自分が続けている努力について説明します」がちょっと意味不明ですが、原文を読めば`Document your own continued efforts to answer your question`とありますので、「自身の質問を解決するために、継続的に取り組んでいることの文書化になります」という意味だと思います。

つまるところ、

- 良い質問かどうかを確認する
- 問題解決のために継続的に取り組んでいる

場合に編集を行うことは良いことであるとされていますが、その逆のケース、初歩的な質問の内容について、編集を繰り返して新着欄の目立つ位置を占拠することについては特に指針がないように思えますが、正しい認識でしょうか？

なにをもって「初歩的な内容とするのか」「継続的な努力をしていないと判断するのか」について、明確なラインを引くことができないと思いますので、個別事例として話をするしかないのかもしれませんが…。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> この機能は悪用すれば、高頻度で編集し続けることで、新着欄を自身のポストで埋めるといったことも可能だと思いますが、この辺りに明確な指針ってあるんでしょうか？

指針は特にないようですし、個人的には別に構わないと思います。

結局は質問者が上位に表示させるのを諦めるか、質問に気づく人が出てくるかの2択ですが、質問者が諦めた場合はそれまでで、質問に気づいた人は気づいた人で「回答」するか「より良い質問に編集」するか「閉じる」か「通報」するかで片付くと思います。

困っているか、迷惑行為かは都度の判断で十分ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> SOは編集を行うことで新着の投稿欄に表示されます。

心当たりがあるので少し弁明させてください。[討議の要約まとめ](/q/1979/)では`[討議の要約まとめ](/q/1979/)`のような記述の仕方を知らず、URLエンコードをそのまま使用していました。その結果、編集中のブラウザが重くなりIMEが正常に動作しなくなってしまったので複数に分けて投稿し上位に表示され続けまた、パーセントエンコーディング部を削除した編集などでその状態が長く続いてしまいました。（現在は`http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1979`で、編集が必要になった時に変更します。

> この機能は悪用すれば、高頻度で編集し続けることで、新着欄を自身のポストで埋めるといったことも可能だと思いますが、この辺りに明確な指針ってあるんでしょうか？

これは、システムとして高頻度な編集で上位に表示されないよう対応してもらうしかないと思います。
けれど、投稿一つに対して５分間はそういった時間が設けられていたと思います。

Comment: 「本日すでに自分の投稿のうち 5 件を編集しています (最も最近の投稿を除く)。次に編集できるのは明日です。」というのもあるようです。